# Jna Linkage Error : How to solve this error while starting cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I am getting the following error while trying to start cassandra.

[image]

My configuration is as follows:

OS:Windows 10
Cassandra:3.11
jdk:1.9

Comment: 137% of percentage quotes are contrived for dastardly purposes. 87% of all Java error reports are class path problems - finding ""native" parts included.

Comment: made image in-place. added some explanation.

Comment: I simply download the tar file from Apache Cassandra website. And i set the JAVA_HOME path after that this error came.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-9608), current latest cassandra 3.11 is still not fully supported for java 1.9. Hence, I would recommend you to try again with java 1.8.